# How to round the corners of a drawing triangle?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to replicate the cursor from this image, but I'm having a little problem with creating the rounded corners. I can't seem to get it right.

[image]

I'm sharing my code with you (you can run it in DartPad if you wish). I'm stuck at the point where I need to round the corners. I've tried several things, but it doesn't seem to work. From what I've roughly understood, it should be done using `drawRRect`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Cursor'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Transform.rotate(
            angle: pi,
            child: CustomPaint(
                size: const Size(60, 70),
                painter: CursorPainter()
            )
          )
        ),
      ),
    )
  );
}

class CursorPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.red
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath(size.width, size.height), paint);
  }
  
  Path drawPath(double x, double y) => Path()
      ..moveTo(x / 2, 0)
      ..lineTo(0, y)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(x / 2, y + 15, x, y)
      ..close();

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Here is what it currently looks like

[image: 2]

If someone has an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the code that I would implement to do something like that, play a little with the values so that you can customize it more to your liking, I think that Transform.rotate is not necessary, If you have time, read the following article, it will help you a lot, good luck!

https://medium.com/flutter-community/paths-in-flutter-a-visual-guide-6c906464dcd0

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Cursor'),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child:
              CustomPaint(size: const Size(50, 70), painter: CursorPainter()),
        )),
  ));
}

class CursorPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.red
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    canvas.drawPath(drawPath(size.width, size.height), paint);
  }

  Path drawPath(double x, double y) => Path()
    
    ..moveTo(x * 0.05, y * 0.1)
    ..quadraticBezierTo(x / 2, -x * 0.10, x * 0.95, y * 0.1)
      //borther right
    ..quadraticBezierTo(x, y * 0.12, x * 0.95, y * 0.2)
    ..lineTo(x * 0.5 + (x * 0.1), y * 0.9)
    //borther bottom
    ..quadraticBezierTo(x * 0.5, y * 1.08, x * 0.40, y * 0.9)
    ..lineTo(x * 0.05, y * 0.2)
       //borther left
    ..quadraticBezierTo(0, y * 0.12, x * 0.05, y * 0.1)
    ..close();

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you. The guide looks very interesting, it will help me.